# How can I execute a statement when a boolean's value changes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a script in Unity.

```
public class WhileOne : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject char1, char2, charChanger;
    bool theTrue = false;

    void FixedUpdate () {
        if (ThingController.howManyTrues <= 0)
            theTrue = false;
        else
            theTrue = true;
    }
}
```

I want to enable another script from this script only when my boolean's value changes from false to true. I have already implemented the boolean's conditions and value assignments, I want to know how to check in an efficient manner when its value changes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show the relevant code...is this Boolean a public property? If so, you can implement some code in the `set` block, i.e. `private bool backingField; public bool PropertyICareAbout { get { return backingField; } set { backingField = value; // do something here when value changes } }`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have added the relevant part of the code to my question. Where exactly should I define private bool backingField; 
and can I write public bool PropertyICareAbout inside FixedUpdate? Because I seem to have a lot of errors right now. Also, what is the logic between this method? I'm afraid I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the boolean variable from field to property and you will be able to detect when it changes in the `set` accessor.

```
public class WhileOne : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool _theTrue;
    public bool theTrue
    {
        get { return _theTrue; }
        set
        {
            //Check if the bloolen variable changes from false to true
            if (_theTrue == false && value == true)
            {
                // Do something
                Debug.Log("Boolean variable chaged from:" + _theTrue + " to: " + value);
            }
            //Update the boolean variable
            _theTrue = value;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        theTrue = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked and I have finally understood! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Bikem, If you like this answer,you should mark it as the answer by checking the 'V' symbol.  That way you give credit to him and show all users that the problem is solved.